# How to pass an array of objects to child component in VueJS 2.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to send an array containing arrays which in turn contains objects to one component from another, but the content from the array seems to be empty in the child component.

I have tried sending the data as a String using JSON.Stringify() and also as an array

My parent component:

```
    data: function(){

 return{
       myLineItems : []
    }
},
created(){
 this.CreateLineItems();
},
methods:{


 CreateLineItems(){
      let myArrayData = [[{"title":"Title1","value":2768.88}],[{"title":"Title2","value":9}],[{"title":"Title3","value":53.61},{"title":"Title4","value":888.77},{"title":"Title5","value":1206.11},{"title":"Title6","value":162.5}]] 
    this.myLineItems = myArrayData;
    }
}
```

My parent component's template:

```
/*

 template: `<div><InvoiceChart v-bind:lineItems="myLineItems"></InvoiceChart></div>`
```

My child component:

```
const ChildComponent= {
    props: {
        lineItems: {
            type: Array
        }
    },
    mounted() {   
        console.log(this.lineItems);
    }

};
```

The parent component is created as so (inside a method of our main component):

```
 var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(InvoiceDetails);
                var instance = new ComponentClass({
                    propsData: { invoiceid: invoiceId }
                });
                instance.$mount();

                var elem = this.$refs['details-' + invoiceId];  
                elem[0].innerHTML = "";
                elem[0].appendChild(instance.$el);
```

If I try to do a console.log(this) inside the childcomponent, I can see the correct array data exist on the lineItems property..but i can't seem to access it.

I have just started using VueJS so I haven't quite gotten a hang of the dataflow here yet, though I've tried reading the documentation as well as similar cases here on stackoverflow to no avail.

Expected result: using this.lineItems should be a populated array of my values sent from the parent.

Actual results:  this.lineItems is an empty Array

Edit:  The problem seemed to be related to how I created my parent component:

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(InvoiceDetails);
                var instance = new ComponentClass({
                    propsData: { invoiceid: invoiceId }
                });
                instance.$mount();

                var elem = this.$refs['details-' + invoiceId];  
                elem[0].innerHTML = "";
                elem[0].appendChild(instance.$el);
```

Changing this to a regular custom vue component fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good in your code.

The issue is the property is not correctly getting passed down, and the default property is being used.

Update the way you instantiate the top level component.

Comment: Isn't an error thrown when javascript variables are accessed directly within template?

Comment: Here is data of my parent component:

data: function(){
        return {
            myLineItems: []
        }            
    },


The values are pushed to this array inside the "created" method of the parent component.

Could this be the issue, is the template being added before the "created" method manages to push the values to "myLineItems" ?

Comment: OK thats good, and shows the empty array.  Now, how are you adding items?  Not all methods are reactive.

Comment: Also, are you getting items using a promise?

Comment: Inside created() of the child component, I am calling a method "setMyLinesData()"

Inside this method I am creating an array (data shown above in the original post), and i set this like so: this.myLineItems = myCreatedArray;

I am not quite sure how you use "promise"..I haven't done so here atleast (not familiar with this unfortunately )

Comment: You should not be directly setting a property in a component.  Emit the result, catch it in the parent, and then set the data in the parent.  Or as a quick hack, this.$parent.myLineItems=...

Comment: I see I was mixing up some parts in my previous comment.

The property is set (directly) in the parent component. Should this be avoided?  

Note:  inside the child component...when I do a console.log(this)  , I can in face see the property with its correct values set.  See screenshot:

https://ibb.co/6Znw5yh

Comment: Is seems your  `this` is not setting the correct data member.  Please post (in question) your declaration of the methods that call and set your data.  That is the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question now showing where the data is set.

Comment: @Sjobi I have updated the solution to reflect your latest update.

Comment: When I did that, i got an error: The data property "myLineItems" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.

Tried setting the default prop value to: [] , but still the array is empty when using :   this.myLineItems

Comment: Please ignore my previous answer. I noticed the code was referring to the parent component. This was a typo on my behalf in my question code..but it was set correctly in the code.

Updated the question to:  I had a typo in my question i see. I had indeed set the variable using : and not = :)

Corrected my question to:  return{ myLineItems : [] }

I still can't get my head around this.. Find it weird that the data seems to be availible when showing the entire object, but not using :  this.myLineItems :/

Comment: Does `console.log(this.lineItems.length)` return 0?  Is InvoiceChart your child component?

Comment: this.myLineItems.length gives an error:  "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

InvoiceChart is the child component yes. Included in the parent components template. I don't know if it matters or not..but the parent component is in turn also a child component of our main component? 

The parent  component of InvoiceChart is InvoiceDetails. Mind you...InvoiceDetails component is perhaps created in a non conventional manner and this might be some of the problem. I have updated my question to show how InvoiceDetails component instances are created

Comment: You stated console.log(this.lineItems); returned and empty array.  You also stated console.log(this.lineItems.length); returned an error.  That does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Now it returns '0'. 

I hadn't set a default value. If only using: props: ['myLineItems']  , it gives the error as this.myLineItems comes out as "undefined". 

While if I set default values as such:  props: { myLineItems: { type: Array, default: [] } }

It length returns 0

Comment: Here is what i get if i do a console.log(this) :  https://ibb.co/bX1Spmy

So the data is indeed there with the correct content...i just can't seem to access it through this.myLineItems

Comment: The property should not even be there.  It should also be wrapped in a reactive wrapper.  Try using Vue.set instead of = to assign the value.

Comment: Seems the whole issue was related to how i created my parent component  (see the question).

Answer (score 1):

Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/znl2yy478p

You can print your object through function JSON.stringify() - in this case all functions will be omitted and only values will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below =>

```
    const ChildComponent= {
    props: {
        lineItems: {
            type: Array
        }
    },
    mounted() {   
        console.log(this.lineItems);
    }
  };
```

Comment: this.lineItems still just returns "[__ob__: Observer]" containing no values :(

Comment: Have you cheked for data in myLineItems??

Comment: Yes, I can see that it contains data (see my original post for what it contains). And can access it fine from the parent component. 

Also in the child component if I do a : console.log(this), I can see that the property lineItems of the child instance, in fact contains the correct data. 

But if I try:  console.log(this.lineItems), it outputs nothing

Comment: Can u create a fiddle?